# How to retrieve an array of data arrMyLatLng function

Tags: javascript

How to retrieve an array of data arrMyLatLng function.
       db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

```
  function queryDB(tx) 
{ 
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Attractions', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

   function querySuccess(tx, results) 
  {
 var arrMyLatLng = [];
 var len = results.rows.length;
 var arrLatitude=[], arrLongitude=[];
 for (var i=0; i<len; i++)
 {
    arrLatitude[i] =  results.rows.item(i).latitude;
    arrLongitude[i] = results.rows.item(i).longitude;
    arrMyLatLng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(arrLatitude[i], arrLongitude[i]);
 }

return  arrMyLatLng  ; // Need this array to manipulate the data from it is outside of the function.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never used db.transaction, but why don't you just pass a callback function to `queryDB`, and call that function inside of `querySuccess`, passing it `arrMyLatLng`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're performing an asynchronous operation which will execute its callback whenever the operation completes. Hence there is nothing that you can return `arrMyLatLng` to. All work with `arrMyLatLng` will need to be done in the callback. One thing you can do is call another function from `querySuccess` and pass `arrMyLatLng` to it:

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {  
   var arrMyLatLng = [];
   var len = results.rows.length;
   var arrLatitude=[], arrLongitude=[];

   for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
       arrLatitude[i] =  results.rows.item(i).latitude;
       arrLongitude[i] = results.rows.item(i).longitude;
       arrMyLatLng[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(arrLatitude[i], arrLongitude[i]);
   }

   someOtherFunction(arrMyLatLng);
}
```

Comment: that is, even using a callback, I can not achieve the desired result?

Comment: @user2244523 What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: may be possible to make an array of global?

Comment: @user2244523 I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to work with `myArrayLatLng`? Making it global won't help because you cannot control when the callback executes. So any code that is dependent on it will need to either be *in* the callback, or be in a function that is called *from* the callback.